Calculating the theoretical value from a multivariate normal distribution
I am trying to calculate the theoretical value of a stock price from tick data given other stocks in a multivariate system. But the issue I am having is with respect to the compounding effect. From Wikipedia, the conditional distribution is given by:
$$
\mathbf{x} =
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{x}_1 \\
\mathbf{x}_2
\end{bmatrix}
\quad \text{with sizes} \quad
\begin{bmatrix}
q \times 1 \\
(N - q) \times 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
\boldsymbol{\mu} =
\begin{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{\mu}_1 \\
\boldsymbol{\mu}_2
\end{bmatrix}
\quad \text{with sizes} \quad
\begin{bmatrix}
q \times 1 \\
(N - q) \times 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
\mathbf{\Sigma} =
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{\Sigma}_{11} & \mathbf{\Sigma}_{12} \\
\mathbf{\Sigma}_{21} & \mathbf{\Sigma}_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
\quad \text{with sizes} \quad
\begin{bmatrix}
q \times q & q \times (N - q) \\
(N - q) \times q & (N - q) \times (N - q)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
\text{then the distribution of } \mathbf{x}_1 \text{ conditional on } \mathbf{x}_2 = \mathbf{a} \text{ is multivariate normal: }
(\mathbf{x}_1 \mid \mathbf{x}_2 = \mathbf{a}) \sim \mathcal{N}(\bar{\boldsymbol{\mu}}, \bar{\mathbf{\Sigma}})
$$
$$
\bar{\boldsymbol{\mu}} = \boldsymbol{\mu}_1 + \mathbf{\Sigma}_{12} \mathbf{\Sigma}_{22}^{-1} (\mathbf{a} - \boldsymbol{\mu}_2)
$$
For simplicity, lets have a 3 stock system and will calculate the theoretical value of $S^0$, given $S^1, S^2$, where $\mu=0$ for all the stocks. Then $\textbf{a}$, would be a $2\times1$ matrix for 1 observation of $S^1, S^2$. The theoretical value would be reduced to:
$$
\bar{\boldsymbol{\mu}} =
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{c}_{12} & \mathbf{c}_{13}
\end{bmatrix}
\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{c}_{22} & \mathbf{c}_{23} \\
\mathbf{c}_{32} & \mathbf{c}_{33}
\end{bmatrix}\right)^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
{x}_{1} \\
{x}_{2}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $\mathbf{c_{ij}}$ would be the covariance from the i-th row and j-th column, and  $x_1, x_2$ are the observed percentage returns from $S^1, S^2$.
The compounding issue I have is that as the price data comes in, it does not occur at the same time intervals for both stock, and so $x_1=0$ or $x_2=0$. The 2 methods I know is:

Take each percentage return as it comes in to calculate the theoretical percentage return and that from the previous value of $S^0$
Take net (running) percentage return since the start, and have a percentage return for each stock at each timestamp.

For $n=1,000$ for each stock with evenly asynchronous price observations, method 1 would result in $a$ being a $2\times2000$ matrix with percentage returns being asynchronous with the value 0. Method 2 would have the same $a$ shape, but always having non-zero values in each row (unless $S_{n_i}=S_0$).
.
But their final values are not the same.
I am not sure which method is a more accurate representation, but I lean towards method 2, since if you ignored all the intermediate values and only used the percentage change from $t=0$ to $t=T$, then you would have 1 percentage return observation for $S^1, S^2$ and would then be able to calculate the theoretical percentage return of $S^0$ from just that 1 observation. And it would give you the same final theoretical percentage return as to method 2. But I am still unsure if method 1 can be used or how to fix it if there is an issue
The python code is:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(42)

n = 1000     # observations for each stock i.e. n-timesteps
m = 3        # 3 stock
S_0 = np.array([35325., 16265., 2535.])     # Starting price vals

# Creating a covariance matrix
vols = np.array([0.1, .1, .1])/ 200
corr_mat = np.array([[1, 0.7, 0.8],
                     [0.7, 1, 0.6],
                     [0.8, 0.6, 1]])
m = len(vols)
I = np.eye(m)
cov_mat = (vols * I) @ corr_mat @ (vols * I)

# Creating Sigma_12 and Sigma_22 from the conditional multivariate normal distribution 
Sigma_12 = np.expand_dims(cov_mat[0, 1:], axis=0)
Sigma_22 = cov_mat[1:, 1:]
inv_Sigma_22 = np.linalg.inv(Sigma_22)

random_pct_returns1 = np.random.uniform(-0.02, 0.02, size=n)
random_pct_returns2 = np.random.uniform(-0.02, 0.02, size=n)

# Making the data be asynchronous where 1 column has val whilst the other is nan for the same row
arr = np.full((int(2*n), 2), np.nan)
arr[1::2, 0] = random_pct_returns1  
arr[0::2, 1] = random_pct_returns2  

arr += 1
arr = np.concatenate((np.array([[1,1]]), arr))    # making the first row 1. 

# Put inside a DataFrame and construct the price path for S_1 and S_2 for a sanity check 
df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
combined_price_df = S_0[1:] * df.cumprod(axis=0)
combined_price_df = combined_price_df.ffill(axis=0)

"""
######## METHOD 1 ########

"""
pct_returns = combined_price_df.pct_change(axis=0)
pct_returns = pct_returns.iloc[1:,:]     # removing nan from row 1

theo_pct_returns_method_1 = Sigma_12 @ inv_Sigma_22 @ (pct_returns.values.transpose())
theo_pct_returns_method_1 = theo_pct_returns_method_1.flatten()

theo_price_method_1 = S_0[0] * np.cumprod(1 + theo_pct_returns_method_1)

"""
######## METHOD 2 ########

"""
# percentage returns since the start
running_pct_returns = combined_price_df.iloc[1:,:] / combined_price_df.iloc[0,:] - 1

theo_pct_returns_method_2 = Sigma_12 @ inv_Sigma_22 @ (running_pct_returns.values.transpose())
theo_pct_returns_method_2 = theo_pct_returns_method_2.flatten()

theo_price_method_2 = S_0[0] * (1+theo_pct_returns_method_2)

print(f"Final theoretical value for method 1: {theo_price_method_1[-1]}")
print(f"Final theoretical value for method 2: {theo_price_method_2[-1]}")
plt.plot(theo_price_method_1,label=fr"$\text{{Method 1}}: S^1_T = {int(np.round(theo_price_method_1[-1]))}$",linewidth=0.5)
plt.plot(theo_price_method_2,label=fr"$\text{{Method 2}}: S^2_T = {int(np.round(theo_price_method_2[-1]))}$",linewidth=0.5)
plt.title("Theoretical value for each method")
plt.legend()
plt.show()

Edit:
If we observed 10 ticks of data, 5 for each stock where $S^1 = 20, 24, 18, 15, 10$ at times $t_1, t_3, t_5, t_7, t_9$ and $S^2 = 10, 15, 12, 8, 9$ at times $t_2, t_4, t_6, t_8, t_{10}$, thus ticking asynchronously, then $\textbf{a}$ becomes a matrix where the columns are the returns for each time-step. Method 1 would be:
$$\textbf{a}=
 \begin{bmatrix}
0.2 & 0 & -0.25 & 0 & -0.1667 & 0 & -0.333 & 0 & \\
0 & 0.5 & 0 & -0.2 & 0 & -0.25 & 0 & 0.125
\end{bmatrix}
$$
For method 2:
$$\textbf{a}=
 \begin{bmatrix}
0.2 & 0.2 & -0.1 & -0.1 & -0.25& -0.25& -0.5 & -0.5& \\
0 & 0.5 & 0.5 & 0.2 & 0.2 & -0.2 & -0.2 & -0.1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Method 2 is effectively resampling the observations for each stock as 1 observation.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
